# Unity IoC Config

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, unity-container

Is there any configuration to tell Unity to share same instance for each resolve?

```
class A:IA {
    A(Iref @ref,IB x) {
        @ref.Exec(() => x.Foo());

    }
    ...
}
class B:IB {
    IC c;
    B(IC c) {
        c=c
    }
    void Foo() { c.Bar(); }
}
class C:IC {
    C(Iref @ref) // I need Unity to give me the same instance that is resolved in Class A
    {
        @ref....
    }
    void Bar() {}
    ...
}
```

I have tried to register `Iref` by `PerResolveLifetimeManager` but the problem I have is it shares the same instance for all dependencies not for each one.
The problem looks like this

```
Class FooController:Controller
{
    FooController(IA test1 , IA test2)
    {
        // Unity resolves Iref one time so it is shared between test1 and also test2! 
        // but what i need is Iref instance for each IA, basically a singleton 
        // scoped just inside IA in order to be shared between Class A and C 

    }

    FooController()
    {
        //so the only solution that resolve it properly is by forcing the resolve manually, 
        // the Unity container instantiates Iref for each instance (test1 and test2) 
        // and of course it's shared between class A and also C for each instance of IA
        IA test1 = container.Resolve<IA>();
        IA test2 = container.Resolve<IA>();

    }
}
```

My question is there any solution to fix this using Dependency Injection?

Comment: Do you mean a singleton?

Comment: yes a signleton but scoped just inside IA resolve, for this case if unity resolve IA he must give a signlethon Iref in order to be shared in Class A and C, but when i have to resolve anothe IA instance he must provide a new instance of Iref in signleton again to be shared inside IA, class A and C

Comment: It might help if you pose a hypothetical or real-world problem to solve here. It is somewhat unusual for services to have any state, so the knee jerk response is that this is an XY problem - don't put state in your services. But if there is a valid reason why your services have state you should demonstrate the reasoning for this in your question. Otherwise it seems like you are just trying to invent a problem that wouldn't exist in the real-world.

Comment: As @NightOwl888 commented it is easy to solve more real-world scenarios where lifetime of objects is tied to something. I.e. there are plenty of questions for "per-request" services for ASP.Net/ASP.Net MVC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply register the IA type with the `TransientLifetimeManager` and all other dependent types, with their own lifetime. That means that IA can have singleton dependencies and they will be resolved as singletons (`ContainerControlledLifetimeManager`), while IA will be resolved on every injection.

> TransientLifetimeManager. For this lifetime manager Unity creates and
>   returns a new instance of the requested type for each call to the
>   Resolve or ResolveAll method. This lifetime manager is used by default
>   for all types registered using the RegisterType, method unless you
>   specify a different lifetime manager.

> ContainerControlledLifetimeManager which registers an existing object
>   as a singleton instance. For this lifetime manager Unity returns the
>   same instance of the registered type or object each time you call the
>   Resolve or ResolveAll method or when the dependency mechanism injects
>   instances into other classes. This lifetime manager effectively
>   implements a singleton behavior for objects. Unity uses this lifetime
>   manager by default for the RegisterInstance method if you do not
>   specify a different lifetime manager. If you want singleton behavior
>   for an object that Unity will create when you specify a type mapping
>   in configuration or when you use the RegisterType method, you must
>   explicitly specify this lifetime manager. If you registered a type
>   mapping using configuration or using the RegisterType method, Unity
>   creates a new instance of the registered type during the first call to
>   the Resolve or ResolveAll method or when the dependency mechanism
>   injects instances into other classes. Subsequent requests return the
>   same instance.

Read more here.